# How to insert Image to database from picturebox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a `PictureBox` and I want to save its picture in a SQL Server database into a `VarBinary` column

Comment: Yes and so what?  That is not a question and even if you had managed to slip in a question mark somewhere it would still be very very far away from the high quality of questions that are expected here.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I didnt exactly get what you meant but here is a piece of code you can use for inserting an image into database from picture box.

```
Image img = picturebox1.Image();
byte[] arr;
ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
arr=(byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));

command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ImagesTable (Image) VALUES('" + arr +    "')";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score -1):

> whoops found it

this is the insert methodes

```
 public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
        {
            ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
            return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
        }

  public static void InsertImageintoSqlDatabaseAsBinary(byte[] imgData)
        {


            using (SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=VIP;Trusted_Connection=True;"))
            {
                sqlconnection.Open();


                // Converts image file into byte[]


                string insertXmlQuery = @"Insert Into ExpertsInfo (Image) Values(@Photo)";

                // Insert Image Value into Sql Table by SqlParameter
                SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertXmlQuery, sqlconnection);
                SqlParameter sqlParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Photo", imgData);

                sqlParam.DbType = DbType.Binary;
                insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
```

and Use of it like below :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


        Image img = picturebox.Image;
        byte[] imgbyte= ImageToByte(img);

        InsertImageintoSqlDatabaseAsBinary(imgbyte);


    }
```